# Gruntfile.js with sass plugin not minify all scss files

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs

Let's talk about Grunt and Sass.

The problem I have is that in the file **css/theme/client.min.css** is minified only **css/theme/source/client.scss** but no traces of the content of **views/scss/cover.scss**.

it's very weird because in other projects, in other Gruntfile.js the same syntax works, and I know it's correct. The Gruntfile.js is well written and compiled without any errors.

The following part is the one not working.

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/theme/default.min.css': 'css/theme/source/default.scss',
                'css/theme/reveal.min.css': 'css/theme/source/reveal.scss',
                'css/theme/client.min.css': [
                    'css/theme/source/client.scss',
                    'views/scss/cover.scss'
                ]   
            }
        }
    },
```

Do you have any idea about it?

Do you need more code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: TBH your first sentence doesn't make any sense... Think you need to fix a filename or two?

Comment: sorry it was a copy/paste mistake.. thank you for notifying

Comment: No Sass error in file `client.min.css` ?

Comment: Any errors, the client.min.css contains only client.scss

Comment: Maybe "grunt -v" would give some more info.

Comment: can you give the file tree of the css and views directory ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  'css/theme/client.min.css': [
  'css/theme/source/client.scss',
  'views/scss/cover.scss'
], <- Maybe this can be the answer of your problem
```

Comment: no, that was a copy / paste mistake too - the code is basically correct, there are no compiling errors.